# Is there a CSS selector that selects a dt and its associated dd elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Definitions lists are a great way to mark up information where some key word is associated with one or more values.

Since there is the semantic association of a dt with **one or more** dd elements, is there a way to use CSS to select these associated items.

Consider the following html:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Foo</dt><dd>foo</dd>
  <dt>Bar</dt><dd>bar</dd>
  <dt>Baz</dt><dd>baz</dd>
</dl>
```

If I want to present this dl as:

```
-------  -------  -------
| Foo |  | Bar |  | Baz |
| foo |  | bar |  | baz |
-------  -------  -------
```

I need a way to say dt/dd pair number one float left, get a border, and so forth.

Right now, the only way I know how to do this is to make separate dls for each set of dt/dd elements:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Foo</dt><dd>foo</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>Bar</dt><dd>bar</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>Baz</dt><dd>baz</dd>
</dl>
```

Which is atrocious from a semantic point of view, these items are all members of one list.

So is there a selector or combination of selectors that will allow me to operate on dt/dd element groups?

**Update**

What I am looking for/proposing is something like a pseudo-element `list-item`, where dl:list-item would select a `dt` and all associated `dd` elements as one item, in much the same way as the `first-line` pseudo-element allows one to select a group of characters as a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in response to knittl's answer.  There isn't room or the capability to adequately respond to knittl's answer in a comment, and this response is not part of the question, as it addresses the answer to the question.  So, I'll go ahead and post it as an Answer.

knittl says that what I am looking for is not possible.  I suspected that was the case, but I could have missed something when reading various standards.

However, the reason provided is demonstrably incorrect.

knittl asserts:

> no, there isn’t because a `<dt>` can
>   have multiple `<dd>`s and the other way
>   round.

If he had stopped with 'no, there isn't' that would have been the correct answer.

So, the claim is that it is impossible because we have an indeterminate number of elements in the proposed grouping.

This claim can be disproved directly by providing an algorithm to produce a set of related elements for any set of dt and dd elements that are children of a dl. Further, it can be disproved by the counter example of an existing pseudo-element that operates over an indeterminate  portion of the document.

The logic to implement a pseudo-element that groups related dt and dd elements is not difficult.  So the number of elements of either type is not germane.

For a given DL element:

- Specify a collection type to contain `dt` and `dd` elements called a `dt_dd_group`
- Start a collection of `dt_dd_group`s called `all_groups`
- Inspect each child element (non-recursive):

  - If the element is a dt:

    - If this is the first element or the previous element was not a `dt`:

      - Create a new `dt_dd_group`
      - Append the new `dt_dd_group` to `all_groups`
      - Append the element to the `dt_dd_group`
    - Else append the element to the current `dt_dd_group`
  - Else if the element is a dd:

    - If this is the first element:

      - Create a new `dt_dd_group`
      - Append the new `dt_dd_group` to `all_groups`
      - Append the element to the `dt_dd_group`
    - Append the element to the current `dt_dd_group`
- Return collection `all_groups`

This algorithm easily partitions a set of dt/dd elements within a dl into related sets.  For any legal dl, including the compliant but pathological case where no initial dt elements are provided:

```
<dl><dd>foo</dd><dd>bar</dd><dl>
```

To say that this mode of selection is impossible due to the indeterminate number or dt or dd elements in such a group is shown to be false.  The number of letters in the first line of a paragraph is also indeterminate, yet the `:first-line` pseudo-element is part of the CSS standards.

It is reasonable to say that the mode of selection I am looking for is not possible because CSS Working Group did not consider the issue, or that they considered it and chose not to include it in current standards for some reason.

So, in summation, while a selector that operate on a group of semantically related dt and dd tags is theoretically possible, **no such selector has been implemented**.

Comment: There maybe no selector that does it directly however I think that using an ID in combination with a general sibling combinator, might do the trick.  See my answer below for code.

Answer (score 3):

no, there isn’t because a `<dt>` can have multiple `<dd>`s and the other way round.

but maybe:

```
dt + dd {  }
```

is enough in your case

Comment: I am aware of the one to many relationship, that is why I said "there is the semantic association of a dt with one or more dd elements".  `dt + dd` does not allow for both the dt and its associated dd elements to be operated on as a unit.

Comment: it’s rather a many-to-many relationship, consider: `<dt/><dt/><dd/><dd/><dd/>`

Answer (score 0):

How about using an ID in combination with a general sibling combinator?

```
    <html>
    <head>
          <style type="text/css">
                #id1 ~ DD { color: red; }
                #id2 ~ DD { color: blue; }
          </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dl>
        <dt id="id1">term 1</dt>
            <dd>def 1a</dd>
            <dd>def 1b</dd>

        <dt id="id2">term 2</dt>
            <dd>def 2a</dd>
            <dd>def 2b</dd>
        </dl>
    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Check out this fiddle, it seems to do what you want ... http://jsfiddle.net/6qEHQ/

Comment: Hey, sorry about your answer getting deleted. Apparently we overlooked your edit at the time. I just came across this question and restored your answer for you.

Comment: The limitation here is that the general sibling combinator doesn't let you select *until* a specific element, so there's no way to use it even with an ID *without* overriding it for a later ID, as shown in your `#id2 ~ DD { color: blue; }` rule.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, for returning my answer.  It was the first time I posted over on SO, I've been on SF for a while,

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "a later ID", aren't ID's unique on a page?

Comment: In your example, `#id2` comes after `#id1`. I guess that should have been "later parent" instead :)